# setText error in get Intent from activity

Tags: android

I am wondering why this is code is error,

Here's my code:

```
TextView txt_loggedName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

Intent intent = getIntent();

String name  = intent.getStringExtra("name");

txt_loggedName.setText(name);
```

i am getting error in this line

```
txt_loggedName.setText(name);
```

! [Syntax error on token "name", VariableDeclaratorId expected after 
     this token
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P1o3.png)

Kindly help me with this one,

Thank you!

Comment: Your question says `txt_Name` but your screenshot says `txt_loggedName`

Comment: that doesnt explain the underlined parts though

Comment: can you fix that error or not?

Comment: can show the lines where you build the intent?

Answer (score 1):

try something:

```
if( intent.hasExtra("name") && intent.getExtra("name") != null ){
   txt_loggedName.setText(intent.getExtra("name"));
}
```

or the answer from Samadhan Medge: txt_loggedName.setText(""+name);

then if the TextView is empty you know either there is no intent extra named "name" or it is NULL

or go and debug with Logcat:

```
Log.d("intent_extra_name", intent.getExtra("name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your intent doesn't contain a "name" extra. You can check it like this:

```
intent.hasExtra("name");
```

Comment: the `hasExtra` method returns a boolean. You can check if you have an extra called "name" with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your name string getting null, replace this as `txt_Name.setText(""+name);`